# Keep the active link marked angluar

Tags: angular, navbar

I used a table for the navigation bar with a list of page names in my power bi report once I click on one of the pages the section id is added in my power bi link in the iframe.

I need to mark the first page in the navigation bar as an "active" link and it changes when I click on each link as I don't have a `routerLink`; `routerLinkActive` didn't work for me.

Here is the piece of code where I want to integrate it:

```
<table class="tab" [ngSwitch]="[myParam]" >
    <tr *ngSwitchCase="1">
      <td class="nav-link nav-link-line" *ngFor="let l of linkDash1" >
        <a (click)="changePage(l.idSection)"> {{l.page}}</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img class="logoGo" src="assets/icons/logo.png" [routerLink]="['/index']">
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

any ideas? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to set which index of your items is selected on the component and then add a css class when the index matches the "active" index using `ngClass`.

Example:

```
// template
<td
  [ngClass]="{ 'nav-link': true, 'nav-link-line': activeIndex === i }"
  *ngFor="let l of linkDash1; let i = index;"
>
  <a (click)="changePage(l.idSection, i)"> {{l.page}}</a>
</td>

// component
export class YourComponent {

  activeIndex: number = null;

  changePage(section: string, index: number): void {
    // your existing code
    this.activeIndex = index;
  }
}
```

alternatively, you could use the `idSection` property. You could use anything, as long as it's unique and accessible in your `ngFor`

Comment: Is "nav-link-line" the class you're using to indicate that the link is selected?

Comment: Thanks the example work now after I had update ngClass ==> [ngClass]="{ 'nav-link nav-link-line':activeIndex === i }"

Comment: I thought that might be the case. I'll update the example code as such.